# Sum of numeric field checkboxes in gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having difficulties in assigning double value (for example 124.00) of label text in asp.net. This label is in content page of .net master page.

But I am having the following two problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var totalAmount = 0; //Defined global variable;

function addval(vals)  //I am passing vals(Double from sever side)
{
totalAmount = totalAmount + vals;
(document.getElementsByTagName("<%= lblCurrentProductTotal.ClientID %>")).value= totalAmount.toString();
}


</script>
```

- Each time "clickCh" is called; this sets the `totalAmount` (a global variable) with the parameter passed. It's like if I pass `145` first time it assigns as `"0145"` and second time if I pass `156`  the totalAmount becomes `"0145156"` as I am expecting it to add as `145+156=301`.
- It's not assigning the value to the label "lblCurrentProductTotal"
  Please let me know if i am missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect you're actually passing strings, not "doubles" (I guess you mean numbers in JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenating strings instead of adding doubles.

Either make sure that vals is passed as a number or turn it into a number using parseFloat like below.

```
var totalAmount = 0; //Defined global variable;

function addval(vals)  //I am passing vals(Double from sever side)
{
    vals = parseFloat(vals);
    totalAmount = totalAmount + vals;
    (document.getElementsByTagName("<%= lblCurrentProductTotal.ClientID %>")).value= totalAmount.toString();
}
```

Comment: And do u want me to declare the global variable as something like float?

Comment: You cannot declare floats in javascript. There should be no need for further global vars, and the totalAmount is declared correctly (provided that we are not discussing avoiding globals :) )

Comment: But the moment i parse the vals to float my global variable declaration is giving an error.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It might be more clean if you could make sure that vals was already a float when the function is called.

Comment: Hey Jacob thanks a ton man! Now i can see the amount updated correctly. ie its adding up the values. But still its not updating in level. So my first problem is solved ...I am working to assign this value on runtime generated client if of my lebel.

Comment: You are using `document.getElementsByTagName` to get the element. That does not look right to me. Are you sure you did not want to use `document.getElementById` instead?

Answer (score 0):

you have tp parse the val to float: parseFloat(val).
and for the label problem:
I think you have to change the `getElementsByTagName` to `getElementById` and give the id of the label
use this code to change the label value:

```
    var label = document.getElementById("<%= lbl.ClientID %>")
    label.firstChild.data="changed"
```

Comment: This level  is rendered at the output as -                          <span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblCurrentProductTotal">R 156</span>            but i tried with getElementById as well as getElementByTag both do not assign value. Although i am able to see by debugging that the countrol is found by the script.

Comment: I changed my code. see it now, you have to get the firstchild of the span and get its data. see my answer now and vote to it if it helps you.